# Flutter keyboard overlapping with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a page with a DefaultTabController that is:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                color: buttonColor,
              ),
              tabs: [Tab(text: "Login"), Tab(text: "Register", key: Key("tabRegistro"))],
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(appBarTitle)),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            new LoginPage(),
            new RegisterPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And for example, the LoginPage build is:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: backgroundColor,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 155.0,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/pet.PNG",
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        emailField,
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        passwordField,
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        loginButon,
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        GoogleSignInButton(
                            darkMode: true,
                            text: "Login with Google",
                            onPressed: () {
                              _sigIn();
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        )));
      }
```

But when I'm writing, the keyboard cover the Textfields and they aren't visible.

[image]

With `SingleChildScrollView` before it works, but now it doesn't work propertly. I have tried to put `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true` but it doesn't work. What could I do to fix this problem?

Comment: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); what does this line mean. it shows error and if i remove it than it works fine for me.

Comment: This line is to unFocus to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The code is Ok, the problem is at Android.manifest.xml. I'm using Android Simulator and to hide the status bar I put these line:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

If i put the original line it works. The original line is:

`android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"`